# Wordpress Blocks My Theme's İmportant Api

Tags: wordpress, api, security, http-status-code-403

I use wordpress for my website. I have a api system in my current theme for follow-unfollow system. When I try to follow or unfollow, my api request blocking. 
My Url; 
https://my_website.com/wp-content/themes/my_theme/api.php? 
I got 403 error. 
How can I solve it? 
I am using Aksimet Anti Spam, iThemes Security, Wp Scan and Loginizier.

Comment: Can you share more details, like the full and exact error message, along with the code involved and your attempts to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try to make a page api and make the api.php a template. Try to access it from there, I'm not sure if any of your plugins refuse access to the wp-content/themes or what but my api is a template on a page :)

Comment: Thanks for answer. I solved my problem. iThemes Sec block all api where in theme or plugin. I closed this settings and working now.